# LuaJava not running script until close

Tags: java, lua

I have added loading and executing of lua scripts to java using LuaJava, but when I run a script such as:

```
print("works")
```

It won't show up until after the program has stopped running.

This is my Java code:

```
LuaState state = LuaStateFactory.newLuaState();
state.openLibs();
state.LdoString(scripts.get(name));
state.close();
```

EDIT: Fixed using this code:

```
LuaState state = LuaStateFactory.newLuaState();
state.openLibs();
state.LloadString(scripts.get(name));
state.call(0, 0);
state.close();
```

Comment: Sounds like the output is being buffered and not flushed until the output stream is closed.  You're going to have to provide more details about how you are instantiating the Lua interpreter and how you are binding its output stream in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The stream used for stdout/stderr is buffering the data. You'll need to explicitly flush the buffer in question.  For example. you might try 'state.LdoString("io.flush();");